# Designing table for document annotation with future columns

Tags: mysql, database-design, rdbms, eav

I am working on a web application that allows students/researchers to annotate `PDF` documents shallowly by (manually) counting interesting phenomena. Right now, there is a total of about 45 of these phenomena, most of which are nominal values, booleans or integers. The database is a MySQL database, and the amount of documents would be between 100 and 500, so the database is quite small.

The application adds these documents and their respective annotations to a corpus which will also be searchable (and filterable based on a large subset of these phenomena).

In the future, some phenomena may be added, or existing ones may be disabled or automatised through automatic tagging, etc.

This could be done by, for example:

### 1. Altering the table and adding columns via the web application

Ultimately the table might become too big (column-wise), but it is easy to implement, even if it seems clumsy to have a table with 60 columns. I'm not sure if it is as inefficient as it seems.

### 2. Storing the annotation part of the web application externally

For example, as JSON documents or in a nonrelational database such as **MongoDB**. This intuitively makes sense as I'm presenting the need for a flexible (and thus nonrelational/schemaless) solution for annotation. But connecting two databases together might unnecessarily increase the complexity of the application. Also, using foreign keys might become impossible this way (?).

### 3. Storing the annotations as one `blob` in a MySQL column

I have virtually no experience with blobs, as I've always avoided them. I read it in [a different question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17500/which-is-better-for-long-term-database-scalability-adding-columns-or-having-key)

### 4. Storing all/new attributes in an EAV table in the MySQL database

Seems like a hacky way to mimic nonrelational behaviour in a relational database. I also read that it could cause performance issues.

I'd love some advice on which method is better or if there is something entirely different I should have a look at.

Comment: I'd go for 2. It's flexible, powerful and easy. JSON fields are a new addition to databases and may seem suspiciously bad practice relying on them, but I suspect this might be more of a cultural thing than technical. I use them all the time (eg for auditing) and they're great.

Comment: @ZiggyCrueltyfreeZeitgeister It seems like you're referring to 3 instead of 2... Can you elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: MySQL 5.7.12's "Document Store" is aimed at this use case.

Comment: Data sharing, transactions, commits, rollbacks. Locks, repeated reads. Strict data typing, foreign keys, referential integrity. If you need all the features (and only you can know it) then choose option one. Or may be web application will do some input vaidation and it's quite enough. Then i'd better opt for JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON documents are ideal for this purpose. MySQL can store JSON documents [via its JSON datatype](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html), and it has a variety of function for extracting information in such documents. However, MySQL doesn't currently have an effective native way of indexing JSON documents for fast search. Googling for "mysql json index" will render several strategies for doing so, some using triggers and external tables, others using indexes on computed columns.

PostgreSQL, however, has very good support for JSON datatypes including indexing, opening up documents as recordsets (using LEFT JOIN LATERAL in combination with `jsonb_each` is very powerful), and GIN indexes that support JSON documents (for both tags and contents). Unless you're heavily invested in MySQL already, PostgreSQL would be a great option for your application. Alternatively, you may want to consider PostgreSQL instead of MongoDB if you'd use it for this purpose alone. Additionally, PostgreSQL can easily access MySQL tables with via Foreign Data Wrappers, it has good support for regex text manipulation, and you can do all sorts of magic on JSON documents through standard perl libraries, using pl/perl stored procedures.

Comment: Thank you. I'm working on XAMPP for Development and I'm using the CodeIgniter framework so I will have to see if it's easy to integrate. If you happen to have experience with that, please let me know.

Comment: @LennartKloppenburg CodeIgniter seems to support PostgreSQL well enough, and there are many stackoverflow entries for both together, so it doesn't seem uncommon.